# Laravel 5 - How to retrieve and set any user database granted roles while login in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5 and i need find a way to establish a new user session parameters from any given user of my database and use it's granted permissions/roles  inside the database, i don't want to use the default root user from Laravel .env file once i login for the first time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're talking about some kind of authentication system, but it's really unclear what you're asking... Laravel `.env` doesn't have a default root user in it (unless you've defined one), and even then, that wouldn't do anything unless you have an auth system to handle it in place already. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to use a dynamic user while loging in, for example if i use username: daniel and password:123 i want that user to be use by my system, not the one im using in my .env file

Comment: That's how an Auth system works. You supply a username and password and it "logs you into the system" as that user. I still don't know what you're saying when you say the one in my .env file. Either way, you should read up on this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: If you want to look for roles in the database, you can implement a Gate or a Policy. Please clarify you question. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization